# Filter for git gui

Tags: git

I am running git on Ubuntu 11.4 (Gnome).

Is there a way to make git gui ignore certain types of files and not display them in the "Unstaged Changes" window?  For one thing I would like it to ignore subdirectories and files that are not source code.  For example I would like it to display changed files with suffices like .php, .css but not with suffices like .jpg, .png.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks,
Peter.

This is what I put in .gitignore

```
*.jpg
*.png
Dracula/*
```

Thanks,
Peter.

Comment: do you have a gitignore file?

Comment: Does a `gitignore` file help you? Or you want to track the `jpg`s files but don't see them in git gui? I think the latter is difficult to achieve...

Comment: I don't want to track jpg files and other files that are cluttering up the "Unstaged changes" window.  I put *.jpg in the gitignore file and restarted git gui but the files I do not want to track still show up.  Thanks, Peter.

Comment: In particular I do not want to track subdirectories.  Thanks, Peter.

Answer (score 1):

Your .gitignore should work for Git Gui.

To ignore a directory named **img/** and all **.jpg** and **.png** files, your gitignore will look like:

```
*.jpg
*.png
img/
```

Put the .gitignore at the top-level of your working directory tree.

EDIT: 
Hmm ... what version of git gui (Help >> About)?  Also, can you describe your tree a little bit (maybe edit your question, since it's easier to format than a comment)?

```
README.txt
src/
   a.php
img/
   x.jpg
   y.jpg
```

Comment: Hey, Peter, did that work for you?  It worked on my machine, but, maybe you have an older version of **git gui**.

Comment: Hi John.  I put the .gitignore file in the directory that was returned by sudo git rev-parse --show-toplevel and added those lines to it.  Unfortunately the only effect was that the .gitignore file was added to the "Unstaged Changes" window of git gui.  I must be doing something wrong.  Thanks, Peter.

Comment: Hmm ... what version of git gui (Help >> About)? Also, can you describe your tree a little bit (maybe edit your question, since it's easier to format than a comment)?  I edited my answer a bit to show you what my tree looked like that seemed to work fine.

Comment: Sorry about the delay replying.  It is git gui version 0.14.0 and git version 1.7.5.4.  Thanks, Peter.

Comment: Your .gitignore seems correct.  If you do `git status` at the shell, are files ignored the way you want?  If so, then, git is behaving correctly and you may just need to update `git-gui`.